# Force download with Swedish characters (åäö) filename

Tags: php, special-characters, force-download

I use the following code and function to force download files and it works great if the file name is not holding Swedish characters like `Å Ä Ö`.

```
$file_id = $_GET['f'];

$sql =  " SELECT * ".
            " FROM attachment ".
            " WHERE attachment_id = ".$file_id." ".

            $res = mysql_query($sql);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
            $filename = $row['filename'];
            $USER_ID = $row['user_id'];
            $Directory_id = $row['directory_id'];
            $target_path = "upload/".$USER_ID."/".$Directory_id."/";


function Download($path, $speed = null)
{
    if (is_file($path) === true)
    {
        $file = @fopen($path, 'rb');
        $speed = (isset($speed) === true) ? round($speed * 1024) : 524288;

        if (is_resource($file) === true)
        {
            set_time_limit(0);
            ignore_user_abort(false);

            while (ob_get_level() > 0)
            {
                ob_end_clean();
            }

            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Length: ' . sprintf('%u', filesize($path)));
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

            while (feof($file) !== true)
            {
                echo fread($file, $speed);

                while (ob_get_level() > 0)
                {
                    ob_end_flush();
                }

                flush();
                sleep(1);
            }

            fclose($file);
        }

        exit();
    }

    return false;

    }
Download($target_path.$filename);
```

I tried to put this on the top of my page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

And:

```
$filename = urlencode($filename);
```

Or:

```
$filename =  htmlentities($filename, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

But still the same problem, I can't open them. But if the filename holds normal English character then it works fine.

Do you have any suggestion what can I put or implement to the function? Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try : $filename = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $filename);

Comment: Maybe this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http

Comment: What is the encoding of the php file you use?

Comment: @Vincent Decaux , thank you Vincent for your replay but it's the same problem. I tried  $path = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $path)

Comment: @Lukas Hajdu thank you for your respond but it was too much information and I didn't get it what to do.

Comment: @bksi Do you mean what kind of file? documents , pdf.....

Comment: No I mean php file that should echo the stuff. If it has other encoding, this can cause issues

Comment: @bksi Hell Bksi. Now I have edited. You can se how I get filnename and how I call the function

Comment: @bksi ... Sorry Hell Bksi = Hello Bksi..... ;)

Comment: No man. every file is encoded in your filesystem. What type of encoding you use when write php files? In your php editor you can easly check.

Comment: @bksi aha now I get you. It's UTF-8 , LOAD AS UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have utf8-encoding in your html-document
(`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>)`

Try to replace

```
$filename = $row['filename'];
```

with

```
$filename = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $row['filename']);
```

So your code would look like:

```
$file_id = $_GET['f'];

$sql =  " SELECT * ".
            " FROM attachment ".
            " WHERE attachment_id = ".$file_id." ".

            $res = mysql_query($sql);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
            $filename = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $row['filename']);   
            $USER_ID = $row['user_id'];
            $Directory_id = $row['directory_id'];
            $target_path = "upload/".$USER_ID."/".$Directory_id."/";
```

But then for the sake of it. Don't use mysql()-functions. Use mysqli or PDO instead with placeholders. Your code is widely for sql-injection attacks.